# Server log rotation

Tags: java, wildfly

I have an application running in Wildfly 8.2.1. In addition to the server.log file in the log directory, my application creates and uses other log files too (also in the log directory). They all end in `.log`. This is dynamic and programmatic using `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`, since the names, contents, and number of files differs from one client to the next.

What I'd like is for Wildfly to automatically rotate these log files too in addition to its own (i.e. `server.log`). I see in standalone.xml there is a `periodic-rotating-file-handler` tag with a `file` subtag that has a `path` attribute. From reading the Wildfly logging documentation, it seems like I can't use wild cards here? So, `path="*.log"`? Is this true? If so, how can I achieve the end goal of Wildfly automatically rotating my log files instead of doing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to rotate log files you'd need to use a rotating file handler. The `periodic-rotating-file-handler` will only rotate it's own file not other files associated with other file handlers.

Since you seem to be creating a log4j file appender have a look at the `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`.